# Буква "й" в начале слова

Tags: орфография

По данным И.В. Васюры, в русском языке есть только три слова, которые начинаются на букву "й", а именно: "йод", "йог", "йогурт".

**Вопрос:** когда в русском языке появилось первое слово, которое начинается на букву "й"?

Answer (score 1):

Название греческой буквы Ι - **йота** (в латыни J - **йот**) Оно вошло в состав выражения - *ни на (одну) йоту*.
Ранее буква именовалась - *иота*.

> ИО́ТА, ы, ж. 1. Название буквы греческого алфавита (ι). ЛП 140.
>
> 1. Перен. Малейшая частица чего-л. Не мог Творцем создаться без расчета Не только цѣлый свѣт — **ниже одна Иота**! Длгрк. Соч. I 113. ◊ Ни единой иоты. Ни одной строчки, совсем ничего (о написанном). На четыре моих письма, в маии посланныя, **ни единыя иоты** получил я до днесь отвѣтствования. Псм Плкрпв 1056.

(ФЭБ, СлРЯ 18 в.)

> П. А. Вяземский. Старая записная книжка (1830-1870)
> Чадаев, особенно в Москве, предначертил себе план особничества и ни на волос, **ни на йоту** от него не отступал.

(Нацкорпус)

Comment: Большое спасибо.